# ruby on rails 3.0 TimeWithZone add hours can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, fixnum

I'm getting a really strange error in my code that I'm hoping someone can help me out with. I have a model which has a created_at column and a duration column I have created. The duration is simply an integer which is assumed to be a number of hours. I am then trying to compare the current time to the created_at time + the duration to see if the row has expired. My code looks like this:

```
@expire_time = purchase.duration.hours + purchase.created_at
if(@expire_time > Time.current)
  #do some stuff if the current time isn't greater than the expiration time
end
```

When I run that first line in the console it works fine, but when I save my code and call it through the route its part of, I get the following error at that line.

ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone can't be coerced into Fixnum

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be the issue/how I go about making this comparison properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem...

this does not work:
purchase.duration.hours + purchase.created_at

but this does:
purchase.created_at + purchase.duration.hours

Comment: Mark your own question as the answer.

Comment: I'd like to know why this is the case. How is the '+' operator defined for TimeWithZone and Fixnum?

Comment: you cant add a TimeWithZone to a fixnum because it seems to try to convert TimeWithZone to a fixnum first to do it. However it seems that "+" of adding a number of hours to a TimeWithZone defined/works as you would expect. I'm afraid I don't have any more detail than that though.

Answer (score 0):

You just saved my life (or at least 2 past hours...), thanks!

`DateTime.current + 7.days`
Works well, return date time one week later

`7.days + DateTime.current`

> TypeError (DateTime can't be coerced into Integer)`